# Cesium redraws entities if the globe loses focus

Tags: cesiumjs

I noticed that the entities displayed on the globe will be redrawn/rendered if I open a dialog within my app, close the dialog, and then move the globe around. Is there something in cesium that resets the globe after regaining focus?

Comment: Entities are supposed to be permanent on the globe unless explicitly removed.  Are you saying you want them to not be there anymore after the dialog is gone?

Comment: @emackey I want them to stay there, but after closing the dialog and moving the globe, it seems like something is causing the data to be treated as if it new data and redraws it. I have a function that compares the data each time the state of the globe changes. If the data has been altered, it would clear the entity collection and add the new data. But, the data is unaltered/has nothing new, so the function should not be called. The function is able to verify data changes every other time, but upon closing the dialog, it thinks the data is different.

No clue why.

Comment: @emackey I will try my best to create a replica of the functions as best as I can in a sandcastle like environment...but this will take some time.